# Is there any way to access pl/sql RECORD TYPE variable through java?

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I have a dynamic query in my stored procedure. The query is fired using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. The result of the query is stored in a PL/SQL RECORD TYPE variable.

I want to access this variable via java. For now, I take the resultset in RECORD TYPE then transfer it to an OBJECT TYPE but this doesn't seem right. Can any one help? Anything will work: either provide the way to store EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  result into OBJECT TYPE or access RECORD TYPE variable in JAVA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second part of the query, yes we can collect the variable into OBJECT TYPE. Hope this below snippet helps.

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE lv_tab IS TABLE OF TEST_OBJ
  /

```
SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
  lvtab lv_tab;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT test_obj(LEVEL,LEVEL+1) FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10' BULK COLLECT INTO lvtab;
  dbms_output.put_line(lvtab.COUNT);
END;
```

Comment: Is lv here is TABLE of OBJECT Type?

Comment: Yes i forgot to attach the object type creation scrit

Comment: I want to fetch in OBJECT TYPE TABLE as I am having multiple record set